# How to make the bot reconnect to the VC if it's disconnected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("IDhere");
    if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
    channel.join().then(connection => {
        // Yay, it worked!
        console.log("Successfully connected.");
    }).catch(e => {

        // Oh no, it errored! Let's log it to console :)
        console.error(e);
    });
});
```

How can loop this? So that if someone disconnects the bot it reconnect again.

Comment: you may be able to use the [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event. Thats emited whenever someone does anything regarding voice. That way you could reconnect the bot once it disconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Worthy Alpaca suggested, you can use the [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event, which passes two parameters: the new [voice state](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/VoiceState) and the old voice state.

If you check the following conditions:

- [`oldState.channelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channelID) exists
- `newState.channelID` doesn't exist
- [`oldState.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=id) equals the bot's id ([`client.user.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=id))

You'll know that the bot left a voice channel. At that point, you can rejoin using [`oldState.channel.join()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel). **However**, you'll always want to check if [`oldState.channel.joinable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=joinable) is true before doing so. This will account for circumstances where the bot wouldn't be able to join back. Maybe if the channel was deleted, or the bot was kicked from the guild, or the bot lost `CONNECT` or `VIEW_CHANNELS` permissions, etc.

Comment: you have a typo here "passes to parameters" -> "passes two parameters" 

Comment: I said I was good at discord I never said I could spell 